# How to test if tal:repeat loop on last pass?

Tags: templates, chameleon

I have the following code in a `Chameleon` template:

```
<span tal:repeat="menu view.site_menu">
    <tal:block tal:condition="menu.current">
        <span>${menu.title}</span>
    </tal:block>
    <tal:block tal:condition="not menu.current">
        <span><a href="/${menu.href}">${menu.title}</a></span>
    </tal:block>
    <tal:block tal:condition="not repeat/menu/end">
        <span> | </span>
    </tal:block>
</span>
```

When I try to render this page I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'RepeatDict' and 'dict'
 - Expression: "not repeat/menu/end"
...
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able by trial and error to find a solutions to my problem.  Here is the working code:

```
<span tal:repeat="menu view.site_menu">
    <tal:block tal:condition="menu.current">
        <span>${menu.title}</span>
    </tal:block>
    <tal:block tal:condition="not menu.current">
        <span><a href="/${menu.href}">${menu.title}</a></span>
    </tal:block>
    <tal:block tal:condition="not repeat.menu.end">
        <span tal:omit-tag="">|</span>
    </tal:block>
</span>
```

This works as expected and puts the separator in between each menu item and not at the end.

I was sure I had tried this before but it is working now.